# php xml to .NET binary format

Tags: php

have anyone here ever try to connect to soap server that implement .net binary encoding(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219175.aspx) using php curl or soapClient..
when ever i try to connect to the url using curl i'm always getting 400 bad request because i need to convert the xml to some .net binary format

thanks...

sample codes

$soap_request ="
";

```
$url    = 'https://webapp.healthcaresynergy.com:8002/demoalpha/HealthCareServiceWCF.svc?singleWsdl';
$header = array(
'Content-type: application/soap+msbin1',
'Expect: ',
'SOAPAction: urn:HealthCareServiceWCF/Login',
'Content-length: '.strlen($soap_request),
  );

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($ch , array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    //CURLOPT_ENCODING        => 'gzip',
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)',
    //CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => true,
    //CURLOPT_STDERR          => $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+'), 
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url ,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => 1, 
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $soap_request,

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $header ,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info   = curl_getinfo($ch);

if($output === false)  {
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

}  else { 
    echo 'Operation success';
} echo '<pre>';

print_r($info);

//echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", !rewind($verbose),     htmlspecialchars(stream_get_contents($verbose)), "</pre>\n";
curl_close($ch);

$s = htmlspecialchars($output);
echo $s;
```

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of the time when we were reverse engineering MSNP (Windows Live Messenger). You need to translate the SOAP to [their bytestream format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219210.aspx).

Here is a library for you:

https://github.com/casperbiering/phpBinaryXml

Update:

> Known/Missing issues:
>
> - only decoding is supported

Stupid me. I'll leave the answer maybe it is helpful, while searching for an encoding lib.

Maybe a workaround would be to compile a .NET console program or similiar for linux and use this as a wrapper / translator.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea Dan, in fact why not expand on that, use 'Topshelf' to make your console app a windows service, then use 'NancyFX' or 'ServiceStack' to provide a JSON based API which can then be called easily from any language.

Comment: @shawty I have only little knowledge about Windows Services and programing those, but I always prefere a fully compliant external wrapper over an almost impossible to hand-craft library ;)

Comment: how can i create a wrapper, sorry guys but i dont know how to program using .net...
but is that possible that i can wrapper .net codes then run it to php code?

Comment: Forget using .NET to run PHP code, it is technically possible but VERY, VERY difficult, and besides trust me, if you can program in PHP, then .NET and C# is easy to pick up.  As for creating a wrapper, well that's an entire question in it's own right, but what I'm talking about here when using 'Topshelf' and 'Nancy' is more of a 'facade design pattern' or a 'bridge design pattern' but written as a man in the middle service application.

Comment: @danfromgermany - if you can write a simple console program, then all you need is topshelf (Can get from NuGet) and a handful of Lambdas to turn that console app into a windows service, search codeguru.com for the .NET nuts and bolts column, Iv'e already blogged about it, and quite recently too.

Comment: @shawty I don't want to do this :D I feel very comfortable in my Linux world. Just threw in my idea.

Comment: @danfromgermany - :-) always a good thing.  FWIW though, both topshelf and nancy work wonderfully under mono on *nix too...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and to be honest, it's always going to fail.

**Why?**

Well, most of the types of services in the .NET world that your highlighting there are 'SOAP' based.

and

Like any good soap based service if you call it with '?wsdl' on the end or a regular get request, you **should** *(if it's written correctly)** get a service description document returned that tells you exactly how to call it.

This 'WSDL' document, can then be interpreted by any decent SOAP library, and then called correctly from within that library, without needing to resort to raw socket calls using tools and/or API's such as Curl.

.NET's soap interface, like most soap implementations, is not designed to be called with a raw URL tool or naked HTTP request, the protocol overhead is just far too complicated to be worth the trouble.

Don't get me wrong however, it **IS Possible** I know, because I've done it, and it wasn't a pleasant experience, and I definitely would NOT recommend anyone to go this route of trying to talk to one of these services unless you have absolutely no other choice.

If you need to use a simple calling mechanism that's easy to work with in Curl (or the PHP Curl API) then might I suggest using 'Generic Handlers' on the .NET side, or the newer ASP.NET Web-API, all of these can be tuned to return the data exactly how you need it returned, and work really well with the more modern and popular JSON format.

If you have a requirement for cross platform binary data exchange, that works great not only on TCP/IP, but over many other channels like Serial, SMS, Radio etc.

Then you might want to consider ***"Google Proto Buffers"*** the serialization on these guys is wonderfully efficient, I work on systems where a TCP based server regularly communicates at socket and byte level with SMS based mobile devices out in the field.

These mobile devices, run Windows CE and at one time had miniature SOAP based endpoints on them just like the ones your asking about, the server services use a mixture of things from PHP to NodeJS, and the maintenance effort we had to manage them was herculean.

Since we changed to using Proto-Buf with them, we've never looked back, serialize it on PHP... De-serialize it on .NET no problem.

Comment: `I've done it, and it wasn't a pleasant experience, and I definitely would NOT recommend anyone to go this route` word! +1 ^^

Comment: is this the google proto buffer https://github.com/drslump/Protobuf-PHP 
so this guy will convert the XML to .Net binary format (mc-nbfs)

Comment: Yes that's google protobuf, but NO it will not convert the XML to .NET binary, the project that @danfromgermany links in his reply will do that, what protobuf will do is if you have control of the code on BOTH sides of the connection, proto-buf will give you a common interface that both sides can easily understand, you will still however need to write both a PHP and a .NET endpoint to make use of the proto-buf technology.

Comment: Addendum: If you want to consume that webservice, then have a look for a decent PHP SOAP library that can query the service for it's WSDL information, and use that, rather than trying to use curl directly.  It's been a while since I've used soap in PHP so I can't recomend one to use, sorry.